# literal hash set in clojure

Tags: hash, clojure, hashset

Whenever I define a hash set in Clojure with the literal notation it scrambles the values around like such:

```
user=> #{1 2 4 6 5}
```

It returned this:

```
#{1 4 6 2 5}
```

But when I put

```
user=> #{1 4 6 2 5}
```

It returned:

```
user=> #{1 4 6 2 5}
```

What's the logic behind this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sets are, by definition, unordered.  So as a matter of interface, the order is arbitrary.  However, a hash set will undoubtedly store its members in some sort of hash table.  So the natural way to enumerate the members of a hash set would be to iterate over the internal hash table.  Therefore, the order in which the elements are produced will depend on the hash values of the elements, and how those values map to the underlying hash table.

That is why the "ordering" of elements appears to be random, but repeatable.

Comment: Humm, probably true, but I would better say a set is unsorted. There are no guarantees on the order of the elements. If you want a sorted set, you can use sorted-set and it will even keep the sort order with succesive conj's: `(conj (sorted-set 1 4 6 5) 2) ;=> #{1 2 4 5 6}`

Comment: Good point.  I added more detail that (hopefully) explains the relationship to hash values without inferring a direct relationship.

Comment: "ordering of elements appears to be random, but repeatable"...given this implementation. An equally valid implementation could include a random shuffling after every read.

Comment: @tar, yes it's possible an implementation could produce a randomly shuffled sequence.  But that seems rather contrived, so I wouldn't consider it to be a very "natural" implementation.  It also wouldn't be a pure function.  Finally, it isn't the way Clojure's `PersistentHashSet`s are implemented.

Comment: There's a reason Clojure's `sorted-set` function exists.

Comment: Absolutely.  But a *sorted* set is not a *hash* set.  This question is specifically about *hash* sets.